# Making after effect compostion matrix using extendscript

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I want to make a Composition Matrix of 25 comps of size 300 x 300px for each comp and align them in the matrix of 5x5 by using Extend Script in After Effects.
This has to be dynamic, if user want to customise the number of comp or the matrix order, he should just enter the value from the prompt window.
Can someone help me out in this.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer well. Do you have any specific questions you need answered?

Comment: I just need a idea, how to setup the loop for aligning the comps

Comment: `var selected = app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers; for (var i = 0; i< selected.length; i++){ < do the things> }`. I suggest you have a look at https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/ and https://extendscript.docsforadobe.dev/